# Creating an "On Demand" event?

Tags: twisted

I am writing a plugin for existing software that will use twisted to communicate with a Denon AV receiver. I've created a method, powerDenonOff, in my protocol for turning off the device, and have the reactor start in a thread when the application launches via runConcurrentThread. I have another method, powerOff, which will be called when the user selects to turn the device off in the software. I'm having trouble figuring out how to call my powerDenonOff method in the protocol from the Plugin class.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class DenonProtocol(LineReceiver):
    delimiter='\r'

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        pass

    def powerDenonOff(self):
        self.transport.write("PWSTANDBY")

    def __call__(self):
        pass

class DenonFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def startedConnecting(self, connector):
        pass

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, one, two):
        pass

    def connectionMade(self):
        pass

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return DenonProtocol()

class Plugin(software.PluginClass):

    def powerOff(self):
        reactor.callInThread(powerDenonOff) #I think this may need to be callFromThread but
                                            #but I left it since that was where the poorly
                                            #worded version of my question left off.

    def runConcurrentThread(self):
        try:
            while True:
                #hardcoded for testing
                port = 23
                host = "111.11.11.11"

                denon=DenonFactory()
                reactor.connectTCP(host, port, denon)
                reactor.run()
        except self.StopThread:
            pass

    def stopConcurrentThread(self):
        reactor.callFromThread(reactor.stop)
```

How do I reach the method in my protocol class? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `reactor.run` more than once, so the loop in `runConcurrentThread` won't work.  You need to start the reactor exactly once per process.  You can call `connectTCP` any number of times and they'll work as long as the reactor gets started at some point.

If `runConcurrentThread` is called in a non-main thread, then you also need to start the reactor without child process support (child processes are only supported when the reactor is run in the main thread).

If `stopConcurrentThread` is called in the same thread as `runConcurrentThread` then it doesn't need to use `reactor.callFromThread`.  However, if `runConcurrentThread` is supposed to block until the plugin is done, then there's no way `stopConcurrentThread` could be called in the same thread, so the use of `reactor.callFromThread` must be correct.

`reactor.run` will never raise `StopThread`.  It will just return.

As far as how to call methods on the protocol instance "from" the plugin, this is just a question about managing references in Python.  Recall that protocol instances are given a reference to their factory (your factory doesn't do this, but it could) and your plugin class is the code that creates the factory.  This means you should be able to write plugin code that refers to the protocol via the factory.

However, you could also use one of the more convenient APIs - for example, endpoints:

```
endpoint = TCP4ClientEndpoint(reactor, host, port)
factory = ...
d = endpoint.connect(factory)
def connected(protocol):
    protocol.powerDenonOff()
    protocol.transport.loseConnection()
d.addCallback(connected)
```

This is just one possible approach - I don't know what kind of connection management makes sense to your application.  If you want to maintain a single long-lived connection, then you might save the `protocol` reference for later use rather than calling `powerDenonOff` and then disconnecting it.  I suspect that since the method here is for turning power off, the connection might not live much longer anyway though...

Crochet will help you do most of the more boring and finnicky parts of this.  I suggest taking a look at it sooner rather than later.

For the rest, you just need to be very clear about what code runs in what thread.  The only Twisted API you are allowed to use in a different thread than `reactor.run` was called in is `reactor.callFromThread`.  You can use this to call other Twisted APIs in the reactor thread.  Also keep in mind that you can only run one reactor per process, and you can only run it once.  The rest is just keeping track of references to the objects you need to use.

Comment: This requires you to tell the reactor before you run it how much time you want it to wait before you run the command, doesn't it?

Comment: To further clarify: I have no way to know when in the future I am going to need to turn the device on. I need to have the reactor already running because I want to listen for when its state changes to update the UI. Since I have no idea when in the future the user wants the command to be run (or even if it will be called at all), I don't understand how to get twisted to handle it.

Comment: Your original question makes it sound like you want time-based events.  It seems this isn't the case, and instead you want GUI-based events?

Comment: My events will be from a GUI, however I will not be creating the interface myself. My plugin will know when a button is pressed because a function in my plugin will be called. When the function in my plugin is called, I want to then in some manner tell twisted to send a message. The function in my plugin will be called after reactor.run() has already been started in a thread.

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem.  When the function is called, then do what you want to do with Twisted.

Comment: I want twisted to realize an event is happening somehow (I don't know how to make it aware) and that it should run a function in the protocol (Something like turnOff, changeVolume, selectSource) to then send the message. While I know I potentially need it to send those functions, I've only found solutions where either you have to know before you even start running the reactor exactly how far into the future you want to run a function. The other I found required you to be building the GUI yourself with a library like GTK.

Comment: Since I can't use those solutions, I have no idea how to get twisted to realize when I actually want it to run a function inside the thread when my method in the plugin in called.

Comment: Your problem is with interacting between the reactor thread and the thing-you-are-a-plugin-for's thread, where it is invoking your plugin function.  But you didn't say anything about threads in your question.  This is effectively a duplicate of many similar questions about threads.  You probably want to use Crochet https://pypi.python.org/pypi/crochet to cooperate between other plugins that may also want to use Twisted.  Other than that, the answer is `reactor.callInThread` http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/13.0.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorThreads.html

Comment: I'll take a look at Crochet once I get Twisted working in my current code, thanks. =) I am still having some difficulty though. I think a lot of the problem is because my original question is pretty poor. I've updated it and I think its a lot more clear what I'm trying to do.